# In Facebook, how can I enable "Shown on Timeline" as default for YouTube activity?

Tags: facebook, youtube, facebook-timeline

When I upload videos to my YouTube account, I know they get posted to Facebook because my friends can see them but I cannot see them myself unless I go to my Privacy Settings, then click "Use Activity Log" in the "Who Can See My Stuff" section, then on the left side bar under "All Apps" click "More", then scroll down and click "YouTube".  Only there can I see a list of my YouTube related posts, and for each one I can choose "Shown on Timeline", and only then can I see that particular post on my Timeline and in my news feed.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get the items to be "Shown on Timeline" by default, and going through all the hassle to change it manually every time I post a video isn't acceptable.

I did stumble upon some article or post online in which someone explained how to do this with Pinterest activity, and it seems that the option to have it "Shown on Timeline" as default was actually effected by a setting on the Pinterest end.  I couldn't find anything equivalent on the YouTube end, though.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your FB "Account settings". there will be an option "Timeline and Tagging" in the left side. click on this tab. then some option will appear in the right side. Go on the "Who can see things on my timeline?" option. After select "Who can see what others post on your timeline?" select friends and or Everyone.
I hope this was your question " how to show your post on timeline by default.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I already have that option set to "Friends".  I want to test something, though... I'll comment again in a moment...

Comment: Sorry.  I was testing to see if maybe setting it to "Everyone" would let it show up but it did not.  The YouTube uploads only appear in my Activity Log on Facebook.  I still have to manually set each one to "Shown on Timeline" after they've been added.

Comment: I really don't why it's not working for you.. For me, I can see all my post included Youtube's videos on my wall. Are you using the new FB version?

Comment: I'm not sure what's considered the "new FB version".  I don't know why i can't see them, either. It doesn't make sense.  When I log in to a secondary FB account that I have, I can see YouTube stuff.  Just seems inconsistent.  It's frustrating.